# parse html tables with lxml

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

I have been trying to parse the table contents from [here](https://nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/fo_underlying_home.htm)
i have tried a couple of alternatives, like

```
xpath('//table//tr/td//text()') 
xpath('//div[@id="replacetext"]/table/tbody//tr/td/a//text()')
```

here is my last code:

```
import requests, lxml.html
url ='https://nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/fo_underlying_home.htm'
url = requests.get(url)
html = lxml.html.fromstring(url.content)
packages = html.xpath('//div[@id="replacetext"]/table/tbody//tr/td/a//text()') # get the text inside all "<tr><td><a ...>text</a></td></tr>"
```

however none of the alternatives seems to be working. In the past, i have scraped data with similar code (although not from this url!). Any guidance will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried you code. The problem is not caused by `lxml`. It is caused by how you load the webpage.

I know that you use the `requests` to get the content of webpage, however,  the content you get from `requests` may be different from the content you see in the browser.

In this page, 'https://nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/fo_underlying_home.htm', print the content of `request.get`, you will find that the source code of this page contains no table!!! The table is loaded by `ajax` query.

So find a way to load the 'really' page you want, the you can use 'lxml`.

By the way, in web scraping, there are also something you need to mention, for example, `request headers`. It's a good practice to set your request headers when you do the http request. Some sites may block you, if you do not provide a reasonable `User-Agent` in the header. Though there is nothing to do with your current problem.

Thanks.

Comment: hi..yes..i realized that the page i was trying to parse is not really the one with actual data. I am very thankful for your suggestions. I an not a pro at parsing, will read about requests headers.

Comment: I tried `curl` to download your page. It seems that in command line, curl could get all data, `curl 'https://nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/fo_underlyinglist.htm' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0'`. If this works for you, you can try python version of curl to load the page.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML page, there is a namespace:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

So, you need to specify it:

```
NSMAP = {'html' : "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"}

path = '//html:div[@id="replacetext"]/html:table/html:tbody//html:tr/html:td/html:a//text()'
packages = html.xpath(path, namespaces=NSMAP)
```

See http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes

### Interpreting Ajax call

```
import requests
from lxml import html

base_url = 'https://nseindia.com'

# sumulate the JavaScript
url = base_url + "/products/content/derivatives/equities/fo_underlyinglist.htm"
url = requests.get(url)
content = url.content
# -> <table>
#    <tr><th>S. No.</td>
#    <th>Underlying</td>
#    <th>Symbol</th></tr>
#    <tr>
#    <td style='text-align: right;' >1</td>
#    <td class="normalText" ><a href=fo_INDIAVIX.htm>INDIA VIX</a></td>
#    <td class="normalText" ><a href="/products/dynaContent/derivatives/equities/fomwatchsymbol.jsp?key=INDIAVIX">INDIAVIX</a></td>
#    </tr>
#    ...

html = html.fromstring(content)
packages = html.xpath('//td/a//text()')
# -> ['INDIA VIX',
#     'INDIAVIX',
#     'Nifty 50',
#     'NIFTY',
#     'Nifty IT',
#     'NIFTYIT',
#     'Nifty Bank',
#     'BANKNIFTY',
#     'Nifty Midcap 50',
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. I incorporated the changes you suggested above. However, the output is still a empty list.

Comment: The reason is simple: there is no *table* in the response! The table is generated using JavaScript.

Comment: yes. i just realized it after being pointed to it by @rojeeer

Comment: What do you think of the result of **fo_underlyinglist.htm**? Is it what you want?

Comment: yes. that was the desired output. I got it by using  fo_underlyinglist.htm as my url link in requests.get(). The rest of the code works fine. I was not aware of the table being generated by Javascript/Ajax. I appreciate your help.